# Getting excerpts from Wikipedia in bulk

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

Is there a way to get all title/excerpt pairs from Wikipedia? To the moment I found two ways:

- Download excerpt dump, but it contains incomplete/invalid excerpts taken as a first line of an article I suppose.
- Request excerpts using MediaWiki API, but it is extremelly slow because you can only get single excerpt per request (bulk query is not working for excerpts):

> /w/api.php?action=query&format=json&titles=Main
> page&redirects&prop=extracts&explaintext=&exintro=

I would like to get excerpts as they are generated by MediaWiki API w/o burdening Wikipedia servers. **Is it possible?**

*P.S.* I need excerpts as a plain text. No wiki text or formatting required.

**Update.** It's possible to get 20 excerpts maximum at once via MediaWiki API:

> *See* https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Bextracts
>
> &exlimit=20

Comment: Download the last [database snapshot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download).

Answer (score 1):

It is not currently possible. Cou could look at the Yahoo abstracts [in the dumps](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/20170420/) which try to do something similar (not very well though). They are powered by [the ActiveAbstract extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:ActiveAbstract).